# Media Query: Image src property change using css

Tags: css, html, media-queries

I'm developing an HTML5 app for Android, iPhone and Windows phone and I'm using media queries to display different image files depending on the screen width.

If I display the image using the CSS `background-image` property, I could change the image file using different CSS classes according to the media query value.  But I'm unable to change the image if it is displayed using the `img` tag.

Is there any way to change the image source associated with the `img` tag using CSS media queries?

Comment: @Alien: Thanks, will follow the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a sprite sheet and alter the `background-position` of a `<div>` or similar (which will replace an `<img>` on the page) to sample a new portion of the sprite depending on your media query criteria.

Example:

HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

CSS:

```css
div
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: url(http://martywallace.com/view/textures/photo/terraria.jpg) no-repeat;
}

@media all and (max-width: 1000px)
{
    div
    {
        background-position: -20px -50px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea to use the sprite, i need to know that, will the background image do all the tasks that img tag do, like i am using an image tag with the anchor tag  like <a><img src="filename.png"/></a> for some buttons. and i need one more help that how do i use background position property if i use different resolution mobile devices, is percen or em value holds good in this scenario?

Comment: @MohamedHussain You can use `<a>` in place of `<div>` for a link. I'm not sure about percent and ems, give it a try.

Comment: @jan: one clarification needed that: is it possible to use div inside anchor tag? i guess it violates the inline block element rule.

Comment: @MohamedHussain Good point. You can certainly use a `span` instead and style it as a `display: inline-block`